# Баг с входящими сообщениями

Tags: дефект, входящие-сообщения

Заметил следующий баг:

Допустим, у меня появилось входящее сообщение. Я открываю выпадающий список, щелкаю на нем левой кнопкой мыши, выбираю "открыть в новой вкладке" и нажимаю на кнопку, чтобы отметить прочитанным. Но когда я открываю новую вкладку, то "единичка" на кнопке "ящика" по прежнему будет висеть. Хотя это сообщение будет помечено как прочитанное. Убрать единичку можно только нажатием на ссылку "отметить все прочитанным".

[image: вот такая ерунда]

Comment: А вы перезагрузите страницу.

Comment: Наверное не то чтобы прям баг, а разработчики просто ленятся пихать некоторые события в вебсокет

Comment: У меня не удаётся воспроизвести. Если в одной вкладке отметить сообщение прочитанным, то в другой единичка также исчезает. Вообще, подобные баги надо постить на MSE, если есть возможность подтвердить хотя бы на паре сайтов. Учитывая, что сейчас можно любое сообщение пометить прочитанным или снять пометку о прочтении, то должно быть легко проверить.

Comment: да оно и в этой же вкладке временами случается. Жмешь на новое сообщение, оно тут же открывается, и в то же время висит непрочитанным.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ там есть уже - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393540/im-clicking-the-same-message-multiple-times-to-get-it-to-clear-is-it-broken-o

Comment: У меня проблема тоже воспроизводится. В прочем, её на MSE уже много раз воспроизводили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ может из-за того, что вы модератор?

Comment: @Зонтик так входящие со всех сайтов отображаются, а модератор я только тут. Вообще со входящими и признаком их прочтения есть глобальная [бага на яблочных устройствах](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385959/339911).

Comment: Но у меня-то устройство не яблочное...